# How to instantiate just one concept in an Ontology with Jena?

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I'm working on how to automatically instantiate an ontology with Jena. I'm interested in instantiating concepts discovered from a set of data.

My problem is that sometimes I need just to instantiate one concept of the ontology. And I'm confused since in Jena, we need a complete Statement to instantiate an ontology.

Assuming that I've the following ontology.

[image]

What would be the statement to instantiate only one concept on the ontology for example `EventType`?

Is it necessary to have a `Statement` to instantiate an ontology ?

or Is my ontology not expressive enough ?

**Edition : My Jena Code**

```
public static void manageOntologies() throws FileNotFoundException{     

    int i,inFrame, lineSize;
    int frameNum = 0;

    Individual individu;
    Resource   resource;
    Statement  statement;
    OntModel   domainModel;

    Vector<String> lines = readFile("data/Trace.dat");

    String[] parts = null;
    String   event = null;

    domainModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(ProfileRegistry.OWL_DL_LANG);
    domainModel.read((new FileInputStream(ontopath)), null);

    lineSize = lines.size(); 

    for(i = 0; i < lineSize; i++){
        parts = lines.elementAt(i).split(" ");
        event = parts[parts.length - 1];            
        resource = domainModel.createResource(xmlbase + "frame" + frameNum);//, domainModel.getOntClass(xmlbase + "Event"));
        domainModel.add(resource, RDF.type, domainModel.getOntClass("Event"));

    }

    System.out.println("Numbre de frame = " + frameNum);

    domainModel.write(System.out);
}
```

And here are is problem encountered

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.add(ModelCom.java:929)
    at soctrace.Intology.manageOntologies(Intology.java:87) -- domainModel.add(...)
    at soctrace.Intology.main(Intology.java:38)
```

**Edition 2 : My OWL/XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY tima "http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:tima="http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <Ontology rdf:about="http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl">       
</Ontology>


<!-- http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#Event -->

<Class rdf:about="&tima;Event">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
</Class>



<!-- http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#EventDuration -->

<Class rdf:about="&tima;EventDuration">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&tima;ValuePartition"/>
</Class>



<!-- http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#EventType -->

<Class rdf:about="&tima;EventType">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&tima;ValuePartition"/>
</Class>



<!-- http://www.soctrace.org/ontologies/tima.owl#ValuePartition -->

    <Class rdf:about="&tima;ValuePartition"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Thanks for any reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that in RDF you store statements, not individual terms or concepts.
However everything has a type, even if it's just `rdfs:Resource` (or in owl typically `owl:Individual` or `owl:Class`). Thus you all always add something via a statement of the form `thing rdf:type Type`, just pick the appropriate type.

In this case presumably `EventType` is a class? In that case:

```
Resource eventTypeResource = model.createResource(eventTypeURI);
model.add(eventTypeResource, RDF.type, OWL.class);
```

However that's such a common pattern you can use:

```
Resource eventTypeResource = model.createResource(eventTypeURI, OWL.class);
```

Or even better use the Jena ontology API:

```
OntClass eventTypeResource = ontModel.createClass(eventTypeURI);
```

(`OntClass` is still a `Resource`, but with some very useful methods added)

Jena provides a nice [introduction to the ontology api](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html).

Comment: Hi, I've try your following code `Resource eventTypeResource = model.createResource(eventTypeURI); model.add(eventTypeResource, RDF.type, OWL.class);`, It work well but his result is adding news (automated discovered) Classes to the ontologie. I want something like this `model.add(eventTypeResource, RDF.object, model.getOntClass('Event'));`. to instanciate an object of the class 'Event'. thanks for your reply !

Comment: Ah, I see. Then just use `model.add(eventTypeResource, RDF.type, model.getOntClass(eventURI));` or simply `model.createIndividual(model.getOntClass(eventURI))` (in the ont api).

Comment: I've try this code but they still not working with an error `resource = domainModel.createResource(xmlbase + "frame" + frameNum);domainModel.add(resource, RDF.type, domainModel.getOntClass("Event"));` what could be the write code ? Thanks for yout time !

Comment: What's the error? "Event" isn't a URI, so you need to fix that.

Comment: I've put my Java code in my question for detail. But the problem is the `add` method of model.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be precise, since you haven't provided your data or ontology (so we can't try your code). However, it is quite likely that this is the problem:

```
domainModel.getOntClass("Event")
```

`"Event"` is not a URI, so it is very unlikely that your ontology has an event class by that name (and if it does, you should change it to use full URI's instead!).

You will need to provide a full URI to `getOntClass`, otherwise it will return `null` because it does not recognise the class. Assuming you provide a suitable value for `EVENT_NS`, then:

```
domainModel.getOntClass( EVENT_NS + "Event")
```